# dpm_detector build fails in linking

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is linking to an unknown library. It seems that it's octave related but I haven't found the correct Ubuntu 10.10 install. I added octave to the core rosdep.yaml for ubuntu 10.10.

This is my error:

```
  Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libdpm_wrapper.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapackgf-3
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas-3gf
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../lib/libdpm_wrapper.so] Error 1
```

This is my change for octave in rosdep.yaml:

```
octave:
 ubuntu: 
  '10.10': octave3.2-headers
  '10.04': octave3.0-headers
arch: octave
macports: octave
centos: octave-devel
debian: octave3.0-headers
opensuse: octave-devel 
fedora: octave-devel
gentoo: sci-mathematics/octave
freebsd: octave
```

It seems that now it needs to link agains liblapack and libblas instead of the gf version. These

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9547/dpm_detector-build-fails-in-linking/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Ubuntu 10.10 a patch can be found here:

[dpm_detector ticket 5081](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/ticket/5081)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0